# StreamWriter did not write to file

Tags: c#, text

Below is part of my code, cannot figure out why the text stream did not write to target file.

```
...
StringBuilder Religion = new StringBuilder();
...         
    if (Religion.Length != 0)
    {

        sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(Dts.Variables["User::RawData"].Value.ToString() + "Religion.csv");
        sw.WriteLine(Religion);
        MessageBox.Show(Religion.ToString());
    }
```

I added the `MessageBox.Show` to help me check whether the `StringBuilder Religion` is empty or not, but it did have all the rows, and I have multiple code block like this for each of my data file, do not know why only for this, the result file is **EMPTY**...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You must close the stream, use [using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) statement..

Comment: Streams need to be closed (and flushed). Without an explicit call you need to wait the Garbage collector to do its work

Comment: thanks guys, but this is the code block in the middle, why the files before and after it get populated, none of the `sw` get disposed after

Comment: using(sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(Dts.Variables["User::RawData"].Value.ToString() + "Religion.csv")){
        sw.WriteLine(Religion);}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use using:

```
...
StringBuilder Religion = new StringBuilder();
...         
if (Religion.Length != 0)
{

    using (sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(Dts.Variables["User::RawData"].Value.ToString() + "Religion.csv"))
    {
        sw.WriteLine(Religion);
    }
    MessageBox.Show(Religion.ToString());
}
```

Alternatively:

```
...
StringBuilder Religion = new StringBuilder();
...         
if (Religion.Length != 0)
{

    sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(Dts.Variables["User::RawData"].Value.ToString() + "Religion.csv"))
    try
    {
        sw.WriteLine(Religion);
    }
    finally
    {
        sw.Close();
    }
    MessageBox.Show(Religion.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Ive, I will try this, can I add `sw.close()` at the end alternatively?

Comment: I added alternative without using and with sw.Close()